# Count Button's Color in C#

Tags: c#, button

I have a problem in my program. I have 3 buttons and the default color is white. When my button back color is changed into red, so my program will count how many buttons are red. I have an idea to use foreach but it doesn't work

```
Button[] Tombol = new Button[]{B1, B2, B3}
int counterbutton = 0;

foreach (Button Tombol2.BackColor = Color.Red in Tombol) //I have problem here. I don't know how to solve
{
  counterbutton++;
}
```

Comment: What is `Tombol2` by the way?

Comment: Tombol2 is all of buttons in Button[] Tombol :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the *right* syntax is;

```
foreach(Button btn in Tombol)
{
    if(btn.BackColor == Color.Red)
       counterbutton++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(Button b in Tombol)
{
    if(b.BackColor == Color.Red)
        counterbutton++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An exemple with linq :

```
var counter = Tombol.Count(b=>b.BackColor == Color.Red)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button[] Tombol = new Button[]{B1, B2, B3}
int counterbutton = 0;
foreach (Button btn in Tombol) //I have problem here. I don't know how to solve
{
  if(btn.BackColor == Color.Red)
  counterbutton++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Button[] Tombol = new Button[]{B1, B2, B3};
            int counterbutton = 0;
            B1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            B3.BackColor = Color.Red;

            foreach (Button b in Tombol)
            {
                if(b.BackColor == Color.Red) //I have problem here. I don't know how to solve
                {
                    counterbutton++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```